# Show that $f \in L^2(\mathbb R)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $1\le p < 2 < q \le \infty$. Show that if $f\in L^p(\mathbb R)\cap L^q(\mathbb R)$, then $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$.The hint is to use Holder and $a=a-b+b$.

I tried to start of with:
$\int_R |f|^2 \le (\int_R|f|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}\cdot (\int_R |f|^q)^{\frac{p-1}{p}}$ and then to try to work on the second term to show that it is finite but to no result. Any ideas on how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\ln$ function is concave. Therefore, for $x,y > 0$ and $0 \le t \le 1$, you have $(1-t)\ln x + t \ln y \le \ln((1-t)x+ty)$. Hence,
$$
          x^{1-t}y^{t} \le (1-t)x+ty.
$$
By taking a limit, the above continues to hold for $x \ge 0$ and $y \ge 0$.

Now replace $x$ by $|f|^{p}$ and $y$ by $|f|^{q}$ to obtain
$$
                      |f|^{(1-t)p+tq} \le (1-t)|f|^{p}+t|f|^{q}.
$$
Choose $t \in [0,1]$ so that $(1-t)p+tq=2$ and you get the result that $f \in L^{2}$, i.e., is square integrable.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $q<\infty$. Note that you can express 2 as a convex linear combination of $p$ and $q$, that is
$$
2=sp+tq,\quad s=\frac{q-2}{q-p}, \;t=\frac{2-p}{q-p}
$$
And we have $s+t=1$, $0<s,t<1$. If we set $r=s^{-1}$ and $r'=t^{-1}$, then $r$ and $r'$ are conjugate exponents such that $|f|^{sp}\in L^r(\mathbb{R})$ and $|f|^{tq}\in L^{r'}(\mathbb{R})$ since $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})\cap L^q(\mathbb{R})$. Therefore, Holder's inequality yields
$$
\int |f|^2 dx=\int |f|^{sp}|f|^{tq} dx\leq \bigl(\int |f|^{rsp}dx\bigr)^\frac{1}{r}\bigl(\int |f|^{r'tq}dx\bigr)^\frac{1}{r'}=\bigl(\int |f|^{p}dx\bigr)^s\bigl(\int |f|^{q}dx\bigr)^t<\infty.
$$

(Note that this actually shows that $f\in L^a(\mathbb{R})$ for every $p<a<q$).